# Mysql: Getting the 2nd earliest date for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

**Desired outcome**:
I want to get the 2nd earliest date for each group.

**Current**:
I am getting the earliest date for each group

**Query**:

```
select * from
(select * from profile_match
where match_available_on is not null
order by profile_id asc, match_available_on asc)
as P1
group by P1.profile_id
```

Example: [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0409/11)

From the example, I want to get:

- 1, '2015-05-20 03:50:11'
- 2, '2015-05-16 03:50:09'

And I hope that the query is not hard-coded with specific profile_id (1 or 2) as my actual data got lots of profile_id. Thanks guys!

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0409/35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the results you want:

```
select t.profile_id, min(t.match_available_on )
  from profile_match t
    inner join (
      select profile_id, min(match_available_on) match_available_on
        from profile_match
        group by profile_id
    ) q
    on t.profile_id = q.profile_id
      and t.match_available_on > q.match_available_on
  group by t.profile_id;
```

By finding the min`match_available_on`, we can then range join against that, and choose the minimum joined value.  This isn't going to be amazingly performant, but it will get the job done.

[updated your demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca7a7/2).

It will not return a row for a profile which has only one date available, as there is no 'second earliest'.